# How to implement this formula with braces and brackets into Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'd like to use Microsoft Excel to compute this formula to find y :

[image]

But I absolutely don't know how to do... It's the first time I see such one.
Could you help me ?

Note : Td2 is a known variable named into a cell.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician. What is Rmin? Excel has functions for COS() and ACOS() and PI(). The different type of brackets in your formula just help group things correctly. The innermost brackets get calculated first, so start with that.

Comment: Tell me, what exactly you are trying to achieve through this formula? Then only possible to find & appropriate method in Excel !! ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention "braces and brackets" in the title, I take it that those are the reason for your question.

Braces and brackets have the same meaning as parentheses, to show the order of calculation, when the order differs from the normal rules (e.g. when addition/subtraction should be performed before multiplication/division).

The reason for using braces and brackets is to visually differentiate levels of nesting. Nested levels of parentheses (whether braces or brackets are used or not) are always solved starting from the most nested level.

Your formula could therefore just as well have been written with only parentheses instead. That is also how you enter it in Excel:

```
=B35*(1-COS(PI()/3-ACOS(1-B36/(4*B35))))
```

Note, that `arccos()` is named `ACOS()` in Excel.

You mentioned that `Td2` is a cell in your worksheet. I guess `Rmin` is also. In the formula above they are represented by cell references B36 and B35 respectively.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that using braces and brackets could replace just parenthesis. Searching the Web, I understood that this was something like a matricial expression. Your answer also helped me to find something I missed after 20 reads of the formula :)  Thanx